# What does 'graft probe’ mean? Is it well-received word?

Tags: meaning-in-context, is-it-a-word

I found the word ‘graft probe’ in the headline of a Associate Press news in today’s Washington Post (April 11) reporting that former president of Egypt, Hosni Mubarak is presently in detention in Sham El-Sheikh in Egypt.

Though I guess ‘graft probe’ means investigation of criminal act such as bribery, corruption and abuse of authority, I can’t find the word in any of English Japanese dictionaries at hand, Merriam, Webster Free Dictionary and Cambridge Dictionary Online. What does 'graft probe’ mean? Is it a day-to-day English word?

The article begins with the following line:

"Mubarak detained for 15 days in *graft probe*: Egypt’s prosecutor general has announced a 15-day detention for the country’s former president to investigate accusations of corruption and abuse of authority."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, it means 'investigation into corruption or bribery'.  The phrase doesn't have a special meaning beyond the combination of the two words *graft* and *probe*.

> *graft*: bribery and other corrupt practices used to secure illicit advantages or gains in politics or business
>
> *probe*: a thorough investigation into a crime or other matter

If the choice of words and the construction seems a bit odd or unfamiliar, that's because newspaper [headline writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline) is a special discipline and the phrases they use would sound strange in normal writing or conversation.

Comment: The phrase doesn't have any special meaning **or existence** beyond the combination of the two words *graft* and *probe*. In other words, this isn't a phrase, it's just two words that happened to end up next to each other in a headline.

Comment: / Martha.I didn’t know ‘graft probe’ is simply combination of two plain words. That’s why I wasn’t able to find entry of the word in any of English dictionaries I cited. As a non-native learner of English, I thought it is press or lawyers’ jargon. Thank you for your quick input.